# Regarding a $\sigma$-algebra restricted on a set. (Show $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)= (\sigma(\mathcal{E}))_T$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let S be a non-empty set. Let $T \subseteq S$. Let  $\mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(S)$ be a family of sets and let $\mathcal{E}_T = \{A \cap T: A \in \mathcal{E}\}$. Define a family by $\mathcal{A}=\{A \subseteq S: A \cap T \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)\}$.

1. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)= (\sigma(\mathcal{E}))_T$

My problem is to show $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_T) \supseteq (\sigma(\mathcal{E}))_T$. This is what I've tried. Let $B \in (\sigma(\mathcal{E}))_T $. Then $B=A \cap T$ for some $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$. We want to show that $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)$. Since $\sigma$-algrabra's are closed under intersections, it suffices to show that $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)$ and $T \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)$. I've already done the latter, but got no idea how to do the former. I don't think the former is even true since I don't think that $\sigma(\mathcal{E}_T) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E})$. So my approach must be wrong.

Comment: This question is also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457687/is-the-restriction-of-sigma-mathcal-e-to-a-subset-u-equal-to-sigma-mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ reads

$$\mathcal{A} = \{A \subset S \::\: A \cap T \color{red}{\in} \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)\}.$$

You already know from the first part of the problem that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Moreover, $\mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Indeed, if $A \in \mathcal{E}$, then $$A \cap T \in \mathcal{E}_T \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T).$$ Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it follows from $\mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ that

$$\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}.$$

Hence,

$$\forall A \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})\::\: A \cap T \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T),$$

and this means that $(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))_T \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E}_T)$.