# Is the restriction of $\sigma(\mathcal E)$ to a subset $U$ equal to $\sigma(\mathcal E\cap U)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal A=\sigma(\mathcal E)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $U\subset X$ is some subset. We know that $\mathcal A_U=\{A\cap U:A\in\mathcal A\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $U$, but do we know that $\mathcal A_U=\sigma(\mathcal E\cap U)$, where $\mathcal E\cap U=\{E\cap U:E\in\mathcal E\}$? One direction of this is trivial, the other I can't figure out.

Comment: What is $\mathcal E$? Just any family of subsets of $X$? This looks like a textbook case for the monotone class theorem. Did you try to apply it?

Comment: $\mathcal E$ is just a family of subsets that generate $\mathcal A$. No, I have not, I'll try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\iota:U\to X$ denotes the inclusion then you are asking whether the following statement is valid:$$\iota^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))=\sigma(\iota^{-1}(\mathcal E))$$

Yes, it is.

Actually it is a special case of a stronger statement:$$\text{ if }f:Y\to X\text{ is a function and }\mathcal E\subseteq\mathcal P(X)\text{ then }f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\tag1$$

Essential for proving this are the following statements:

- If $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ then $f^{-1}(\mathcal A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.
- If $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ then $\{A\in\mathcal P(X)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal B\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

(try to prove this yourself, it is not really difficult)

According to the first bullet we find that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. This with $f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ so that we conclude that: $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))\tag2$$

According to the second bullet we find that $\{A\in\mathcal P(X)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. This with $\mathcal E\subseteq\{A\in\mathcal P(X)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\}$ so that we can conclude that:$$\sigma(\mathcal E)\subseteq\{A\in\mathcal P(X)\mid f^{-1}(A)\in\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\}$$or equivalently:$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))\subseteq\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\tag3$$

This completes the proof.

---

Statement $(1)$ is a nice tool, especially part $(3)$. If e.g. $f:Y\to X$ where $Y$ is equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ and $X$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ then - if $\mathcal E$ generates $\mathcal A$ and we want to prove that $f$ is measurable - it is enough to prove that $f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\subseteq\mathcal B$. From this it follows directly that $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subseteq\mathcal B$ hence also:$$f^{-1}(\mathcal A)=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subseteq\mathcal B$$

Comment: I knew about this result, but it didn't cross my mind to apply it to the injection. Thanks!